# How to multi select with Edit2D

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the Edit2D tools in the Forge Viewer.  I have single selection working, but is is possible to multi-select with these elements?  I have found the Autodesk.BoxSelection tool but that doesn't seem to work with Edit2D elements.  It would be great to have a window selection system like that one but for Edit2D elements.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `Autodesk.BoxSelection` tool is built to work with the actual elements of designs in the viewer canvas. The `Edit2D` extension renders its content in a different way (in an `<svg>` element), so they are not compatible.

As for the multi-selection, the `PolygonEditTool` does have an undocumented boolean property called `enableMultiselection` but it does not seem to be working. Let me report this to the engineering team, and update this answer once I get their feedback.

Comment: Ok great thank you.  It would be great if that could be enabled and functional.    Let me know what they say.